# Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Collider[]' to 'UnityEngine.Collider'

Tags: c#

I'm following this tutorial by blackthornprod:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNQQLr0E9TY
trying to create a roguelike level generator for my game. I've followed the code exactly, however I've switched some of it to be 3D and generating on the x and z axis instead of the x and y.

The code:
`

```
 private void Move()
    {
        if (direction == 1 || direction == 2) // right
        {
            if (transform.position.x < maxX)
            {
                Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x + moveAmount, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                transform.position = newPos;

                int rand = Random.Range(1, 4);
                Instantiate(rooms[rand], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

                direction = Random.Range(1, 7);
                if (direction == 3)
                {
                    direction = 2;
                } else if (direction == 4)
                {
                    direction = 5;
                }
            } else
            {
                direction = 5;
            }       
        }
        else if (direction == 3 || direction == 4) // left
        {
            if (transform.position.x > minX)
            {
                Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x - moveAmount, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                transform.position = newPos;

                int rand = Random.Range(1, 4);
                Instantiate(rooms[rand], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

                direction = Random.Range(3, 6);
            } else
            {
                direction = 5;
            }   
        }
        else if (direction == 5 || direction == 6) // down
        {
            if (transform.position.z > minZ)
            {
                Collider roomDetection = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 1, room);
                if (roomDetection.GetComponent<RoomType>().type != 3 && roomDetection.GetComponent<RoomType>().type != 4 && roomDetection.GetComponent<RoomType>().type != 5)
                {
                    roomDetection.GetComponent<RoomType>().RoomDestruction();

                    int randBottomeRoom = Random.Range(2, 4);
                    if (randBottomeRoom == 3)
                    {
                        randBottomeRoom = 2;
                    }
                }

                Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z - moveAmount);
                transform.position = newPos;

                int rand = Random.Range(3, 5);
                Instantiate(rooms[rand], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

                direction = Random.Range(1, 7);
            }
            else
            {
                stopGeneration = true;
            }

            
        }
        //Debug.Log(direction);
```

The line that the error is on is
`Collider roomDetection = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 1, room);`

The specific error is 'Assets\Scripts\LevelGeneration.cs(91,42): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Collider[]' to 'UnityEngine.Collider''.

I've tried change the Collider to be Collider[] but that produces a whole host of errors saying that is doesnt recognise GetComponent so I'm pretty sure that isnt it.

Comment: `OverlapSphere` doesn't return *a single collider*, but *multiple ones*. You can not handle a collection of things the same way as a single thing, even if you know the collection will allways ever just contain a single item. You may however get a specific item from that collection, e.g. by using its index.

Answer (score 1):

The error translates to "Cannot convert an array to a single object".

It's on this line here, as you say

```cs
Collider roomDetection = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 1, room);
```

It looks like this method returns an array. If you want the first one and can be sure it's populated, get it via the index

```cs
Collider roomDetection = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 1, room)[0];
```

Comment: I think it would be safer to first null checking the result from `Physics.OverlapSphere()`. Then you can be sure that [0] will return a value

Comment: @Roe Definitely would be. I was simply giving OP the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

The exception highlights that you are trying to convert an array to an object.
In your case the array and object are of the type `Collider`.

It would be best to first get the result of `Physics.OverlapSphere()` and checking if it is null or has any values.

```
Collider[] roomDetections =  Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 1, room);
```

note how the type is `Collider[]` instead of `Collider`, the brackets show it is an array of type `Collider`.

You can now check if `roomDetections` is not null and has atleast 1 value. This is done to be sure that you have a valid value to work with.

```
If (roomDetections == null || roomDetections.Length == 0)
{
    return;
}
```

Now your code knows roomDetection has atleast 1 value. If you only want the first value simply get it with`[index]`

```
Collider roomDetection = roomDetections[0];
```

Since `Physics.OverlapSphere()` return an array It is safe to assume that there are cases where multiple collisions can exist at the same time. You will have to process all of the possible collisions to prevent skipping over the not selected values